# Rename [pdb-ms] to [pdb-files] (or [microsoft-pdb]?)

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Looks like [pdb-ms](/questions/tagged/pdb-ms) has its ugly name to resolve ambiguity with [pdb](/questions/tagged/pdb) (Python debugger).

(I'm afraid to ask about/imagine somebody's ill fantasy led to this `pdb-ms`. Have you seen before even once on SO a similarly called tag before naming so?? No.)

To persist unambiguity and name the tag properly I propose `pdb-files`.

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid, you're legend on [so] in the way you edit good questions to be great.

Comment: @abatishchev. I don't understand. What's wrong with `pdb-ms`? `ms` for Microsoft makes sense.

Comment: @doubleDown: This is uncommon for SO suffix notation instead of natural language notation, that's my point.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Emm. Didn't get. sorry. Criticism? Sarcasm? Joke? Elaborate please. This is important for me. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Hey? Any response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and renamed it to [pdb-files](/questions/tagged/pdb-files). That one seems right.